# Query to hide duplicate rows column data. Don't want to remove a duplicate row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want a SQL Server query to hide duplicate rows column data. I don't want to remove the duplicate row, rather conditionally display data as blank.

When, I run this SQL query:

```
select 
    [Vch No.], [Vch Type], [Vch Ref],
    [Date], [Party Name], [Sales Ledger],
    [Amt], [GST Ledger], [TaxAmount], [Total]
from 
    [AccountData]
```

I am getting this output:

[image]

But, I need output in this format:

[image]

In the second print screen, I don't what to display a value of [Vch Ref], [Date],[Party Name], [Sales Ledger], [Amt] and Total.

Comment: You should really do this at the application layer and not in the database.

Comment: I am exporting data to excel and don't have application layer in between.

Comment: They aren't really duplicate rows as the GST Ledger is different and you want to display that

Comment: Yes, I want GST ledger and GST column is not duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like crazy one solution, but you can achieve it using windowed function `ROW_NUMBER()` and using `CASE` expression check if row number is higher than 1, something like:

```
select 
    [Vch No.],
    [Vch Type],
    case when rn > 1 then '' else [Vch Ref] end as [Vch Ref],
    case when rn > 1 then '' else [Date] end as [Date],
    case when rn > 1 then '' else [Party Name] end as [Party Name],
    case when rn > 1 then '' else [Sales Ledger] end as [Sales Ledger],
    case when rn > 1 then '' else [Amt] end as [Amt],
    [GST Ledger],
    [TaxAmount],
    case when rn > 1 then '' else [Total] end as [Total]
from (  
    select 
        [Vch No.],
        [Vch Type],
        [Vch Ref],
        [Date],
        [Party Name],
        [Sales Ledger],
        [Amt],
        [GST Ledger],
        [TaxAmount],
        [Total], 
        row_number() over (partition by [Vch No.],[Vch Type],[Vch Ref],[Date],[Party Name],[Sales Ledger],[Amt],[GST Ledger],[TaxAmount],[Total] order by [Vch No.]) rn
    from [AccountData]
)x
```

Look at datatypes, if there `Amt` is INT you should convert it to string if you want to get blank value.