# How to produce a SQL Server report by making values null if the record is duplicated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a record set based on a query in SQL Server:

```
INV # Item Description QTYSold GROSSSales CASHSales CardSales Customer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
001   Item1            2       20         10        10         CustA
001   Item2            2       20         10        10         CustA    
002   Item9            1       50         50                   CustB
```

I want the report above to be like this one:

```
INV # Item Description QTYSold GROSSSales CASHSales CardSales Customer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
001   Item1            2       20         10        10         CustA
      Item2            

002   Item9            1       50         50                   CustB
```

Notice that the QtySold, Gross Sales and Cash Sales CardSales and Customer Name is omitted. How do I produce this kind of report to make the information blank if the `Inv` has the same `inv#` and the other columns to be the same?

Comment: Make the change at the application layer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server query to hide duplicate rows column data. Don't want to remove a duplicate row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437159/sql-server-query-to-hide-duplicate-rows-column-data-dont-want-to-remove-a-dupl)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if previous value is the same as current value in INV column. If it is the same in "CASE WHEN" clause you can put value or null. Here you have a resolution how to obtain previous value: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/

If you will get the previous value in select than you can put another select souranding it and check values something like this:

```
select Item, CASE WHEN INV=INVPrev then INV else null end as 
INV, ....
from
(
    select Item, INV, LAG(INV) OVER (ORDER BY INV) INVPrev ...
    from table1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below `SQL Query` which could help you to achieve the above Result :

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INV# ORDER BY INV#) R1,
            INV#,
            [Item Description],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY QTYSold ORDER BY INV#) R2,
            QTYSold,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GROSSSales ORDER BY INV#) R3,
            GROSSSales,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CASHSales ORDER BY INV#) R4,
            CASHSales,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CardSales ORDER BY INV#) R5,
            CardSales,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY INV#) R6,
            Customer
     FROM <TableName>)
     SELECT CASE
                WHEN R1 > 1
                THEN ''
                ELSE INV#
            END INV#,
            [Item Description],
            CASE
                WHEN R2 > 1
                THEN ''
                ELSE QTYSold
            END QTYSold,
            CASE
                WHEN R3 > 1
                THEN ''
                ELSE GROSSSales
            END GROSSSales,
            CASE
                WHEN R4 > 1
                THEN ''
                ELSE CASHSales
            END CASHSales,
            CASE
                WHEN R5 > 1
                THEN ''
                ELSE CardSales
            END CardSales,
            CASE
                WHEN R6 > 1
                THEN ''
                ELSE Customer
            END Customer
     FROM CTE;
```

**Desired Result :**

```
INV # Item Description QTYSold GROSSSales CASHSales CardSales Customer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
001   Item1            2       20         10        10         CustA
      Item2            
002   Item9            1       50         50                   CustB
```

Hope, it will help you.